# PHP Cake Adding a Controller to all views

Tags: php, cakephp, view, controllers

I am new to PHP Cake (php level intermediate), my problem is I am working on a site and are using a program to build a review based site. When you are logged in at the top right corner there is the Welcome, followed by the name of the user.  My goal is adding the users profile photo instead of there display name.  The error I get is that the var doesnt exist, and I am unable to locate the variable within the controller.  Unfortunately for some reason the users profile photo will only show up when on the Account page. My thought is there is a controller on the view that has the function that returns the users Profile photo, in Cake Php how do you make a controller a global property.

There are probably more variables needed within this question please let me know so I can fill in the info.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source for the view that is rendered when the Account page is requested? Where is it getting the image from?

Comment: I have and I used the same code inside the area I want it to be rendered at. Let me dig through and find the code and I will post it.

Comment: Just remember that calling the code that the view uses is no good if the controller isn't passing that information to the view when it's time to render. If you're asking a different view to display info it doesn't have, then it won't work. Likely, you will need to pass the path to the user's avatar image to each view that requires it.

Comment: If you are accessing a controller from a view you do something fundamentally wrong: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html

Comment: Im sure im explaining this wrong, the controllers are based on what view is present or do the controllers say what view is being viewed?